# how to implement photo album application?

Tags: iphone

I am implementing photo album application same as default photo album application in iphone.
can any body suggest me how to start?

Answer (score 3):

I've written a simple and easy to use photo browser called MWPhotoBrowser. I decided to create it as Three20, while very good, was too heavy/bloated as all I needed was a photo viewer. Take a look:

MWPhotoBrowser can display one or more images by providing either UIImage objects, or URLs to files, web images or library assets. The photo browser handles the downloading and caching of photos from the web seamlessly. Photos can be zoomed and panned, and optional (customisable) captions can be displayed. The browser can also be used to allow the user to select one or more photos using either the grid or main image view.

[image: MWPhotoBrowser Screenshots]

Comment: @ Michael: I'm trying to implement a photo viewer using the code from the apple sample PhotoScroller (WWDC 2010). If I add a navigation controller, the layout of my pages gets messed up. I noticed you use a navigation controller and your pages layout is perfect. Did you do something particular to make it happen?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the Three20 project started by Facebooks Joe Hewitt, it contains several reusable controls like a photo viewer which mimics the iPhone's Photos app.

"TTPhotoViewController emulates Apple's Photos app with all of its flick n' pinch delight. You can supply your own "photo sources", which works similiarly to the data sources used by UITableView. Unlike Apple's Photos app, it isn't limited to photos stored locally. Your photos can be loaded from the network, and long lists of photos can be loaded incrementally."

http://github.com/facebook/three20/

Comment: any suggestions without using 320?

Comment: Well unless you have a profound objection against using a third party control, I would highly recommend using Three20 if it fits the bill. The Three20 project originated from the Facebook app & has been used by lots of other iPhone apps, it's kind of proven technology & has some very nice & powerful features. I'd use Three20 & use the gained time on other parts of your app. No need to reinvent the wheel, unless you want to learn how it's done.

Comment: Come to think about it, why not have a look at Three20's code & make your own version, it'll give you a good idea of how it could be done. I think the license permits that, although you should check that first.